# Exporting layer symbolized in two different ways with qgis2web?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, symbology, qgis2web

I have a layer containing all the counties of the US. I would like to symbolize this layer for presentation based on two different attributes, say total population and population per square mile, using colour ramps for each.

Only one symbolization would be presented at a time, so one would view one symbolization or the other by turning on or off the higher layer.

I want to export this map using `qgis2web`. I can achieve this effect by duplicating the layer and setting the symbolization appropriately, but this results in two large `.js`-files being written containing the feature sets, which are identical.

Is there a way to symbolize a single layer to achieve this effect? Rule-based symbolization does not achieve this goal as far as I can tell.

I have QGIS 3.4.2 and the latest version of `qgis2web`

Comment: Which export format are you using in qgis2web?

Comment: I'm using openlayers but am not wedded to it

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the layer in QGIS as you described. To get rid of the duplicated large JS files, open `layers/layers.js` in a text editor. Look for lines like this:

```js
var features_airports_0 = format_airports_0.readFeatures(json_airports_0,
```

The JS variable `json_airports_0` is the feature data from the JS file. So, if you have two layers using the same data, replace the JSON variable name of the second with that of the first. For example, change the following line:

```js
var features_planeStations_1 = format_planeStations_1.readFeatures(json_planeStations_1,
```

to:

```js
var features_planeStations_1 = format_planeStations_1.readFeatures(json_airports_0,
```

You can then delete the exported data file `layers/planeStations_0.js`.

You can go further in `layers.js` to deduplicate the code to handle this case (same underlying exported data), but the above solution gets rid of the double data download.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. I made the edit suggested above. I also edited the index.html file to remove the <script src=layers/planeStations_0.js><\script> call (which showed as an error in the debugger since it couldn't be found)., but now the layer with the substitution is not correctly symbolized. All the polygons are filled with white. Since one of my colors in the symbolization is white, I can't tell if this is some sort of default or just using the wrong value.